# I need to redirect my website link from https://ravisah.in/index.php to ravisah.in by HTACCES file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my website to redirect all given below to ravisah.in

1. https://www.ravisah.in/index.php
2. www.ravisah.in
3. www.ravisah.in/index.php
4. ravisah.in/index.php

Please help me to do this.

My htaccess file code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ravisah.in[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ravisah.in/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: My SEO said to me that ---> you have to do this for seo ranking

Comment: Is there any other option to redirect https to http (if i don't want to purchase SSL certificate)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

This will permanently redirect **/index.php** to **/** .

Comment: Its working fine for ravisah,in/index.php redirect to ravisah.in Thank you so much Sir but is this the only solution for all this? i mean to say https is not redirecting

Comment: @Ravisah This should work on both https and http. try Clearing your browser's cache if you are having this problem.

Comment: Sir i am using private window. I need to do if any one enter https://ravisah.in it should be redirect to http://ravisah.in but its not happening saying this error ---> Your connection is not secure

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no any solution for this i only have to purchase SSL Certificate for the website.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess file for 301 redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.ravisah.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ravisah.in/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www.ravisah.in/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ravisah.in/$1 [L,R=301]

**Used for remove www from url**
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ravisah.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ravisah.in/$1 [L,R=301]

**Used for https to http**
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

**Used for remove index.php** 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

For SSl implement You must have SSl certificate